# Xamarin.iOS not found provision profiles in Visual Studio 2019, 2022

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, certificate, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019 or 2022 doesn't recognize active provision profiles for Xamarin.iOS.
My activities to resolve the issue:

1. Removed bin and obj folder at Visual Studio Project.
2. Removed old profiles on Windows from here: **%LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\iOS\Provisioning\Profiles**
3. Removed profiles on Mac OS:
   **~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles**
4. Removed certificates from **Keychain Access** on Mac OS.
5. Created new certificates and provision profiles at Apple Developer site.
   [image]
6. Download and install certificates and profiles for XCode
7. Created new project at MacOS with the same identifier like in Visual Studio project.
   [image]
8. Open in Visual Studio my project and connecting to MacOS.
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
   And I observe, that Visual studio not found Developer Profile and for Release mode set old removed profile.
   The option with automatic preparing is not fit, because VS just create yet a new profile.
   Are there any idia to resolve it?

Comment: Did you follow the microsoft document? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning?tabs=windows

Comment: For debug you can use **Automatic** and for release you need to use **Manual**

Comment: Yes, I did follow the document about "Automatic Provisioning for Xamarin.iOS". This is not good way, because Visual Studio atomatic create new profile and certificate and dont recognized early created profiles. In this way when I upload created .ipa file was error "not founded distribution profiles". Also was problem with push notifications on phisical device at the develop time.
I tried to use only "Automatic" was error "Development profile not found".
Release with "Manual" mode VS defined removed profile, there isn't recognize the new Distribution profile.

Answer (score 4):

I resolved the issue of updating provisioning profiles as follows:

For for **Release** profiles:

1. Clear all provisioning profiles under path **~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles**
2. Add developer account in XCode:
   **XCode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> "+" -> AppleID**
   then click "**Download Manual Profiles**"
   [image]
3. **XCode -> File -> New -> Project -> App** ->
   Choose Team and check Bundle Identifier.

[image]
Bundle ID must be the same like in Visual Studio project in **Info.plist**.

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.your_identifier</string>
```

4. Set required profiles in XCode project:
   [image]
5. Updated VS 2019 on Windows
6. Updated on Mac:

Xamarin.iOS:  `https://aka.ms/xvs/pkg/macios/15.0.0.18`

Xamarin.Mono: `https://aka.ms/xvs/pkg/mono/6.12.0.107`

7. Restart Mac OS and Re-connected to Mac from Visual Studio.
   Now Release profiles were updated in VS.

[image]

For **Debug** provision profile:

Developer profile was not recognized, and I choose "Automatic Provisioning" in Visual studio.

[image]
The project was successfully launched for debugging.
A very important problem remained - push notifications did not work in debug and release mode.
The problem was resolved when I removed Xamarin folder from cache on Mac OS:

```
~/Library/Caches/Xamarin
```

When I rebuilt the application, push messages began work in debug and release.

Answer (score 1):

Here are all the steps you can try:
1.Modify the **"Scheme"** to **"Automatic Provisioning"** and check if it works.

2.Clear all provisioning profiles under path **~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles.**

3.Check if the bundle ID in the Mac is consistent with the bundle ID of your project.

4.Follow the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?tabs=macos) Manual provisioning for Xamarin.iOS to create new profiles.

6.Update the VS to the latest.

5.If all the steps doesn't work, try to report a problem on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=8).

Comment: I tried the steps, and they didn't resolve the issue. The steps lead the error: "An error occurred while uploading certificates. An object reference does not point to an instance of an object."

Comment: check this question https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/567336/xamarin-apple-account-error-there-was-an-error-whi.html