# No matching profiles found Xamarin forms Visual Studio Mac

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I am not sure if I am doing something completely wrong, but I keep getting the following error in Visual Studio for Mac when trying to sign my Xamarin forms app "No matching profiles found"

A bit of background, I created a Xamarin Forms app for iOS and Android.  I followed the steps here to create a provisioning profile etc [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=macos#:~:text=Xamarin.iOS%20apps-,Create%20and%20install%20an%20App%20Store%20provisioning%20profile,-iOS%20uses%20provisioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=macos#:%7E:text=Xamarin.iOS%20apps-,Create%20and%20install%20an%20App%20Store%20provisioning%20profile,-iOS%20uses%20provisioning)

I have removed and re-added my Apple developer account in Visual Studio multiple times, same on Xcode.  I've manually downloaded the provisioning profile and double-clicked to install it, no change, still the same error.

I thought it might have been the app I created, so I created a brand new dummy test app, deleted my old provisioning profile and stuff from the Apple developer website, created a new identifier on the Apple developer site, set the BundleID to explicit and gave it the exact same name as the Bundle identifier in my Info.plist for the new dummy app I created.  Created a new profile, downloaded with Xcode, manually, signed into and out of my apple developer account in Visual Studio for Mac and Xcode and still I get the same error, even with this new dummy app.

I have deleted the profiles from the ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles folder too before re-downloading, makes no difference.

Have I missed something or am I doing something wrong?  I am trying to set up the app to use TestFlight so I can limited people access it and test it, but at this stage I'm completely blocked by this.

I am using Visual Studio Mac 2022.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the config of your "iOS Bundle Signing", could you post a screenshot, eg. is it Automatic provisioning or Manual? (Tip: once done on the website, leave it, just check anything wrong locally, it does annoy sometimes.)

Comment: Yep, will do that.  It's set to Distribution automatic.  When I do that, it shows up as no matching profiles.  Although when it's set to Developer, there does seem to be a profile.

Comment: Based on your description, I found an article which solved this problem. Here is the website: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70536957/xamarin-ios-not-found-provision-profiles-in-visual-studio-2019-2022

Answer (score 1):

I worked out what the problem was by following this tutorial on YouTube.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fkBRXzotbzw

Basically I had created the wrong profile type on the Apple site when creating the provisioning profile. I should have selected App Store Distribution but I was selecting App Store Developer I think.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).